# How to check if a tab is clicked?

Tags: jquery, select, tabs

my question is simple.

i have 2 tabs and i want to alert the tab that i am gonna select

```
$( '#social_edit_pannels' ).tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        var firstSelect = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
        alert(firstSelect);

        if (firstSelect == 0) {
            alert("0");
        }
        else if (firstSelect == 1) {
            alert("1");
        }
    }
});
```

just that this example checks the for the tab that is already clicked..

any ideas?

Comment: so what's your question?  It's a little unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to find out which tab was just selected, however using the method you have gets the tab that was selected previously.

Just call `ui.index`, if you want the element it is under `ui.tab`

```
$('#social_edit_pannels').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var theSelectedTab = ui.index;
        if (theSelectedTab == 0) {
            alert("0");
        }
        else if (theSelectedTab == 1) {
            alert("1");
        }
    }
});
```

**code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/2fNra/2/).**